# How to check for env variable in gatsby-config's plugin array?

Tags: environment-variables, gatsby, conditional-operator, gatsby-plugin

In *gatsby-config.js* when trying to check for an environment variable in the plugins array:

```
process.env.GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_ID && {
  resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-google-analytics',
  options: {
    trackingId: process.env.GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_ID,
  },
},
```

throws the terminal error of:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'resolve') TypeError:
> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'resolve')

trying to isolate with a ternary:

```
const analytics =
  process.env.GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_ID &&
  process.env.GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_ID !== undefined
    ? {
        resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-google-analytics',
        options: {
          trackingId: process.env.GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_ID,
        },
      }
    : ''
```

and in plugins:

```
module.exports = {
  // removed code
  plugins: [
    analytics,
  ],
}
```

yields the same result. Verified plugin is installed in *package.json*:

```
"dependencies": {
  "gatsby": "^4.24.7",
  "gatsby-plugin-google-analytics": "^4.24.0",
},
```

In Gatsby how can a check for an env variable be completed before loading the plugin?